# How to consolidate data in a recursive array

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, ecmascript-6

I am having array of items with following order:

```
const arr = [
  {
    group: { id: "group1", groupname: "groupname1" },
    categories: [
      {
        id: "cat1",
        categoryName: "category1",
        total: 5,
        available: 2,
        subCategories: []
      },
      {
        id: "cat2",
        categoryName: "category2",
        total: 15,
        available: 12,
        subCategories: [
          {
            id: "cat3",
            categoryName: "category3",
            total: 15,
            available: 12,
            subCategories: []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    group: { id: "group2", groupname: "groupname2" },
    categories: [
      {
        id: "cat4",
        categoryName: "category4",
        total: 25,
        available: 22,
        subCategories: []
      },
      {
        id: "cat5",
        categoryName: "category5",
        total: 50,
        available: 25,
        subCategories: []
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

This needs to be converted into array of recursive items, witj key, name, and children properties. The result would be like this,

```
[
  {
    "key": "group1",
    "name": "groupname1",
    "total": 20,
    "available": 24,
    "children": [
      {
        "key": "cat1",
        "name": "category1",
        "total": 5,
        "available": 2,
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "key": "cat2",
        "name": "category2",
        "total": 15,
        "available": 12,
        "children": [
          {
            "key": "cat3",
            "name": "category3",
            "total": 15,
            "available": 12,
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "group2",
    "name": "groupname2",
    "total": 75,
    "available": 47,
    "children": [
      {
        "key": "cat4",
        "name": "category4",
        "total": 25,
        "available": 22,
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "key": "cat5",
        "name": "category5",
        "total": 50,
        "available": 25,
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I am able to bring down to the above structure using the following snippet.

```
const formatter = (data) => {
  const recursiveTree = (item) => {
    if (item.group) {
      const {
        group: { id, groupname, total, available },
        categories
      } = item;
      return {
        key: id,
        name: groupname,
        total: total || 0,
        available: available || 0,
        children: categories?.map(recursiveTree)
      };
    }
    const { id, categoryName, total, available, subCategories } = item;
    return {
      key: id,
      name: categoryName,
      total: total || 0,
      available: available || 0,
      children: subCategories.map(recursiveTree)
    };
  };
  return data.map(recursiveTree);
};
```

I am stuck at deriving total and available of the root note. This node should derive its total and available from its children values. Can someone help me how to do this recursively? This could be n level too

Comment: What would be the expected value for those root properties in this example? And what if you create those properties in a completely separate function? Do you see any problem to do that?

Comment: @trincot edited the question with required info! any pointers would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add some post-processing. Replace this:

```
  return data.map(recursiveTree);
```

with:

```
  const result = data.map(recursiveTree);
  for (const item of result) {
      if (!item.children) continue;
      item.total = item.children.reduce((total, child) => total + child.total, 0);
      item.available = item.children.reduce((total, child) => total + child.available, 0);
  }
  return result;
```

Comment: should `!item.children` be `!item.children.length`? because I dont want to recompute for the ones that are not root node

Comment: This `for` loop only mutates the objects at the top level. There is no recursion.

Comment: That `if` condition is only to deal with cases where root nodes have no `children` property. Maybe this never happens. In that case you can do without it.

Answer (score -1):

One approach separates out the reformatting of your input structure and the totaling of properties.  Here we have an non-mutating version that works like that:

```js
const restructure = (xs) => xs .map (x => ({
  key: x ?.group ?.id ?? x .id,
  name: x ?.group ?.groupname ?? x .categoryName,
  total: x .total ?? 0,
  available: x .available ?? 0,
  children: restructure (x .categories ?? x .subCategories)
}))

const sumOn = (field) => ({[field]: fld, children = [], ...rest}, _, __, kids = children .map (sumOn (field))) => ({
  ...rest,
  [field]: fld + kids .reduce ((t, kid) => t + kid [field], 0),
  children: kids
})

const process = (xs) => 
  restructure (arr) .map (sumOn ('total')) .map (sumOn ('available'))

const arr = [{group: {id: "group1", groupname: "groupname1"}, categories: [{id: "cat1", categoryName: "category1", total: 5, available: 2, subCategories: []}, {id: "cat2", categoryName: "category2", total: 10, available: 5, subCategories: [{id: "cat3", categoryName: "category3", total: 15, available: 12, subCategories: []}]}]}, {group: {id: "group2", groupname: "groupname2"}, categories: [{id: "cat4", categoryName: "category4", total: 25, available: 22, subCategories: []}, {id: "cat5", categoryName: "category5", total: 50, available: 25, subCategories: []}]}]


console .log (process (arr))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Here **`restructure`** converts your slightly odd input into a consistent recursive structure.  **`sumOn`** takes a field name and returns a function which totals values of that field by recursively adding those of each of its `children`.  (This would be slightly cleaner with a `sum` helper; but we can leave that as an exercise.)

Our main function, **`process`**, simply calls `restructure` with the input, and then maps `sumOn` over the results twice, once with `'total'` and once with `'available'`.

I find this a very clean way to break down the problem into reusable chunks and simple steps.